# Old 90's cartoon about a boy who could stop time

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

It's a cartoon from the 90's I think.

A boy and a bunch of his friends were trying to stop the main antagonist. 
The rest of the boy's friends are pretty blurry for me because I was watching this as a little kid. For sure there was one more human character and some talking animals or something.

The antagonist was a Demon-like figure, who was missing one of his horns. If he could retrieve it, all things would go really bad for the protagonists. The demon was the boss of many minions. He was mostly shown sitting on a throne, giving orders.

There was some kind of device which could freeze time. I remember that they used it on a lighthouse, and the storm waves became as still as rock. It was a major item that they used on daily basis to stop time and help them. I do not remember if it was a watch or a clock. One thing is sure, only the main character used it.

The channel was Polonia 1, a Polish thing. They do not have a list of their programs from the 90's sadly.

Comment: Do you remember any more details? How many were in a team? Was animation like anime or like western animation? Were there more antagonists, with demon as their boss, or was demon working alone? On which channel did you watch it? That sort of thing.

Comment: There was a boy, and the rest of them is pretty blurry for me because I was watching this as a little kid. For sure there was one more human character and some talking animals or sorts.
The demon was the boss of many minions. He was mostly shown sitting on a throne, giving orders.
The channel was Polonia 1, a polish thing. They do not have a list of their programs from the 90' sadly.

Comment: @Kowalien - So you watched this show on Polish TV? Could it have been an original production from Poland?

Comment: It was not. I remember that always the voice over crept me out very much.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It could be the Japanese anime *"Pōru no Mirakuru Daisakusen"* ([Paul's Miraculous Adventure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul%27s_Miraculous_Adventure)), though it's from the 70s.

It was originally run in Japan in 1976-1977, and in later years it was dubbed into other languages and thus broadcasted all over the world, including Poland.

A couple of images showing the good guys, from the site [Anime News Network](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=1682):

[image]
[image]

The protagonist, the eponymous **Paul**, is the boy with orange hair and blue suit.

The antagonist is a devil-like monster called **Belt-Satan**; it has a pair of horns, but in an episode Paul manages to break one horn and diminish his evil powers.

[image]

Paul has a strange magic puppet whose powers include stopping time and transporting Paul, his dog Toppe and his friend Nina in another dimension.

Comment: YES!! O MY GOD THANK YOU! 
I was searching this for years!

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you're referring to Venger from [Dungeons and Dragons](http://www.dungeonsdragonscartoon.com/2009/08/venger.html).

[image]

Comment: There were multiple episodes about time-stopping; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uc7dcvGAZ_U

Comment: Close, but not him. That demon was more muscular. The remaning horn was shorter, and he usually was sitting on a throne.

Comment: If it was a girl, I would have said this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princess_Gwenevere_and_the_Jewel_Riders but because it is not, I'll have to keep looking.

Comment: Valorum the case is there was a major item that they used on daily basis to stop time and help them. I do not remember if it was a watch or a clock. One thing is sure, the main character only used it.